# How set scrolling to colorbox after resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I resize colorbox :

```
parent.$(.....).colorbox.resize({width:300})
```

But I want to set the horizontal scroll. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(parent.document).find('iframe body').css({'overflow':'scroll'});
```